# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Undefined setting 'eclipseSkipProject

Tags: sbt, sbteclipse

While migrating my project ot Play 2.4, and sbt eclipse plugin 4.0.0, I get the following exception in my build file:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Undefined setting 'eclipseSkipProject in Scope(
Select(ProjectRef("Some git url with #commit",root)),This,This,This)'!
```

This follows up on [this issue](https://github.com/typesafehub/sbteclipse/issues/304) since I just want a better workaround than modifying the original cached sub-projects by adding the sbteclipse 4.0.0 plug-in to each of them.

My `build.sbt` file is the following:

```
lazy val server = (project in file("server"))
   .settings(scalaVersion := "2.11.7")
  .dependsOn(leonProject)

lazy val leonProject = RootProject(uri("https://github.com/epfl-lara/leon.git#5bf8a57cc03ae5ccbd890e3f4f0121a6f9dd1bb2"))

EclipseKeys.skipProject in leonProject := true

EclipseKeys.preTasks := Seq(compile in Compile)
```

and the `project/plugins.sbt` for a sbt version 0.13.9

```
resolvers += "Typesafe Releases" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbteclipse" % "sbteclipse-plugin" % "4.0.0")
```

How does it come that `Eclipse.skipProject in leonProject := true` does not have any effect ?